# Spark Explode between 2 Dates

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 3.2, and trying to explode data between 2 months, so that I can get a column which contains all months between those 2 dates.

```java
dataSetFromFile = dataSetFromFile.withColumn(
  "MONTH",
   functions.explode(functions.sequence(
      functions.lit("2016-02-01").cast(DataTypes.DateType),
      functions.lit("2016-05-31").cast(DataTypes.DateType),
      functions.expr("INTERVAL 1 month")
   ))
);
```

It's giving me output as

> MONTH 2016-02-01 2016-03-01 2016-03-31 2016-04-30 2016-05-31

Expected Output should be:

> MONTH 2016-02-01 2016-03-01 2016-04-01 2016-05-01

Can you please let us know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to timezone.

**Solution 1**: Change DateType to TimestampType:

```
dataSetFromFile = dataSetFromFile.withColumn("MONTH",functions.explode(functions.sequence( functions.lit("2016-02-01").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType), functions.lit("2016-05-31").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType), functions.expr("INTERVAL 1 month"))));}
```

**Solution 2**: Set timezone to UTC:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
dataSetFromFile = dataSetFromFile.withColumn("MONTH",functions.explode(functions.sequence( functions.lit("2016-02-01").cast(DataTypes.DateType), functions.lit("2016-05-31").cast(DataTypes.DateType), functions.expr("INTERVAL 1 month"))));}
```